# undefiend function using connect-flash middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my app.js

```
app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});
```

and in my jade file I have

```
!= messages()
```

I open the page it says undefiend is not a function function. I already restarted my server, I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: You provided few information: How do you declare flash `var flash = require('connect-flash');` or something else? What part of your application says *undefined is not a function*; the server log, the browser console or something else? Is there other code that could produce the error message. Perhaps it is not caused by connet-flash but by another module. If possible show all of you code files.

Comment: yes I used `var flash = require('connect-flash');` in my app.js. It's this line `!= messages()` that caused the problem, what make you think it's caused by other module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `!= messages()` causes the problem then the error must occur on the server while rendering the jade file. The jade compiler is povided with a data object that contains a message method.

This message method is provided with res.locals.messages and set with the express-messages call. From all I know up to now I would asume that you positioned the code above after you configured the route to page. Then the page is rendered before you set the message method. In that case reorder the `app.use` calls, so the route is defined at last.

Hope that help!

Comment: so what is the solution here? I declared `var flash = require('connect-flash');` before my routes

Comment: @3106579 The require is not the problem, probably you called `app.use(flash())` and `app.use(function ...` after you defined the route. Then, if a request comes in, the route is executed and after that the other middleware is executed which should run before the route handler because the route handler need the message function the middleware induces to the local hash. But if you do not update your question and show me the order of your calls, I can only guess. And I think that's the reason why some other people downvoted your question ;-)

Comment: you're welcome ;-) Btw: that's the reason why I try to answer question with just a few information. If it works, I can feel like Sherlock Holmes ;-)